# Making changes to PATH permanent

Tags: environment-variables, latex

I'm trying to set up Latex, and as part of it need to add to the `$PATH`.  Something I read (probably on here) said modifying `/etc/environment` was better than adding to `.profile` (I think because it changes things for all users?).

I've done this, and then when I run `. /etc/environment`, for the rest of that terminal session everything works fine.  When I open a new terminal though, the commands such as `latex` don't work again.  Restarting the computer also doesn't make the changes to `/etc/environment` be effective across shell sessions.

What can I do to make these changes happen system wide?

**UPDATE:** I ended up installing through the PPA mentioned in the comments, which installed Tex Live 2016 (and set the environment variables) with no issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be asking two different questions. The first is related to change variables system-wide and the other related to make LaTeX work so here is the answer to the two:

## Change environment variables System-wide

As [described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#System-wide_environment_variables) you can add a file under `/etc/profile.d/` which has the `PATH` variable in it:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<your particular latex path>
```

Call it `/etc/profile.d/latex-path.sh` and will be sourced by any shell you log in.

If you want to change the `PATH` variable only for your user, the preferred method is to edit the `~/.profile` with the same line

## Make LaTeX work with no hassle

LaTeX package can be installed from the universe repositories as [described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaTeX#Installing) and no need to change the `PATH` variable. Make sure you have enabled the universe repository and input:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install texlive
```

Or if you like the full distribution (this will install a lot more packages so grab a cup of coffee):

```
sudo apt install texlive-full
```

Comment: I was avoiding installing through `apt` as it's on the 2015 version still, and I wanted to install the 2016 version.  I've found [this](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/texlive) ppa that seems to provide the 2016 version, so I'll try installing from there.

Comment: I always try to find the `apt` way first. Manual installations are fragile and tend to break things. Glad you found it

Comment: @Mark Yeah you can try using that PPA. I wrote something to that effect at http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/324930/5106.

Answer (score 4):

`/etc/environment` is created and maintained by `pam_env` PAM module, not by your shell (so you should not `source` it). This file is read by typical login programs. So you need to logout/login in the usual manner to see the changes (assuming you are not modifying the `PATH` from somewhere afterwards).

On my system, it is read by:

```
% grep -l '^[^#].*pam_env' /etc/pam.d/* 
/etc/pam.d/atd
/etc/pam.d/cron
/etc/pam.d/lightdm
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-autologin
/etc/pam.d/lightdm-greeter
/etc/pam.d/login
/etc/pam.d/polkit-1
/etc/pam.d/sshd
/etc/pam.d/su
/etc/pam.d/sudo
```

If it is not being set to the exact declared value even after restarting you computer:

- You might have made some syntactic mistake, note the declaration syntax would be `KEY=VALUE` (per line) so for example `PATH=/foo/bar:/spam/egg`
- You are overwriting the `PATH` afterwards e.g. from a shell session initialization file